# JSP implicit objects are Singleton objects?

Tags: jsp, object, singleton, implicit

I am very keen to know about JSP's implicit objects implementation. My simple question is that are they Singleton objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are constant field values. See 
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jspapi/javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext.html  and
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jspapi/constant-values.html
Also, if you are using Tomcat, then look in its work folder at a translated file. You will see their creation in the _jspService method.